# Как оптимизировать код с time

Tags: python, время

Пытаюсь сделать уникальный код для id-продукта из даты и времени, т.е. (день недели + месяц + год + часы + минуты + секунды), код получился громоздким, как его упростить, получив тот же результат? В результате получаю код, к примеру: 3132022235137

мой код:

```
timeid = time.localtime(time.time())

a = str(timeid.tm_mday) + '#' + str(timeid.tm_mon) + '#' + str(timeid.tm_year) + '#' + str(
timeid.tm_hour) + '#' + str(timeid.tm_min) + '#' + str(timeid.tm_sec)

b = a.split('#')

c = "".join(b)
```

Comment: Такой id не будет уникальным, потому что он даст одинаковый результат например для времени 01:21:03 и 12:01:03

Comment: а впереди ведь еще дата - число, месяц, год?

Comment: Очевидно, если дата одна и та же, то id не будет уникальным

Comment: Кроме того, для дат «2 декабря» и «21 февраля» id тоже могут оказаться одинаковыми

Comment: 2.12.2022 01:21:03 = 21220221213 , 2.12.2022 12:01:03 = 21220221213 = ой! А как быть?

Comment: Как быть — ну хотя бы добавлять нолики в числах меньше десяти. А если уж добавлять нолики, то можно воспользоваться стандартными функциями преобразования даты в строку и не городить велосипедов: `c = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Comment: Но лучше не использовать время вообще, как предлагает Qwertiy

Comment: смотря что за продукт, если это один и тотже продукт разных партий, то можно для сохранения последовательности

Answer (score 0):

Зачем добавлять символ, чтобы его тут же удалить? Нужно убрать добавление # в переменную `а`, после этого остальные две строчки с `b` и `c` станут не нужны.

```
a = str(timeid.tm_mday) + str(timeid.tm_mon) + str(timeid.tm_year) + str(timeid.tm_hour) + str(timeid.tm_min)  + str(timeid.tm_sec)
```

*Кстати, если нужно удалить какой-то символ, то проще применить replace, чем разбивать строку в список и потом соединять обратно.*

И если уж вам хочется делать ID, основанный на времени, то берите сразу Unix-время

```
timeid = str(time.time()).replace(".","")
```

Точность там доли секунды и даже если выполнить дважды подряд, то будут разные значения.

Comment: тогда они складываются, по-другому пробелы остаются

Comment: Не остаётся никаких пробелов.

Comment: Спасибо, забыл, что в str обвернул!

Comment: `str(int(time.time() * 10 ** 6))` чтобы длина не скакала рандомно

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения!

Answer (score 0):

Не надо делать id на основе времени. В случае перевода часов они могут совпасть. Перевод может быть из-за синхронизации времени, перехода на летнее или зимнее время, смены часового пояса (как официального, так и, например, при перелёте с ноутбуком).

Лучше используй [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Переделаю )

Answer (score 0):

В подомном случае я использовал

```
version="1." + datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d-%H%M'),
```

Но можно и просто

```
datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Год и месяц переносятся вперед чтоб при сортировке легко находить новую и старую версию.